# The significance of ayahs beginning with "Say"

Tags: quran, tafseer

Has there been scholarly discussion of the significance (or subtlety) of the ayahs beginning with "Say"? For example:

> **Say: He is Allah, the One! (112:1)**

versus

> **All praise is due to Allah, the Lord of the Worlds. (1:2)**

(There is nothing special about these choices of examples other than they came to my mind at the time of writing.)

The analyses I am seeking are, in what ways would the meaning of the above ayahs would be different if there was no "Say" in the first example, and the second example started with "Say"?

Comment: I assume this is too broad or hard to answer the Qur'an has hundreds of verses starting with "say" and discussing all of them would be difficult there's even a thesis on this topic. There are examples of verses where "say" sounds somehow weird and needs to be discussed. And this is only about verses where "say" is included if we start making comparisons between those where it was left out or who are similar it could take pages if not books to answer. Generally "say" comes as an order to either the prophet or the Muslims and usually it comes to correct something wrong!

Comment: @Medi1Saif That's why I have not asked for a direct answer, simply asked whether there has been a scholarly discussion that I can read.

Comment: Some scholars say it shows the prophet muhammad pbuh conveyed the qurab excatly how it was said to him.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there has been extensive discussion, but some people have discussed it.

In the case of Surah Ikhlas, the reason it was revealed (Sabab an-Nuzul) is itself a reasoning for the existence of the "Say" in its beginning.

There are many reported narrations for why it was revealed but what they have in common is that it was revealed at a question or demand by the Kuffar to the Prophet (SAW) to describe Allah.

Hence, it is almost like Allah saying, "As a response, say this, this, and this."

Although most tafasir do not mention this explicitly, they imply it with the mention of the Sabab an-Nuzul. Ibn 'Ashoor, however, mentions it explicitly in his tafsir.

Other reasons are also mentioned in some tafasir for the "Say."

It should be noted that most of the verses starting with "Say" have obvious reasoning for it. That is probably why most scholars didn't discuss what was obvious. For example:

> **Say, [O Muhammad], "If the home of the Hereafter with Allah is for you alone and not the [other] people, then wish for death, if you should be truthful."** (2:94)

The context is a back and forth debate with the Jews, and Allah is teaching us what to say in this debate.  I would say a large majority of the "Say" verses are in a similar context of debate with Jews, Christians, or Mushrikeen.

Only in the contexts where it is strange would discussion be required.

That said, in the tafsir Mafaateeh Al-Ghaib, 43 benefits are mentioned for the "Say" in the beginning of Surah Kafiroon, and three are mentioned for the "Say" in Surah Falaq.

Answer (score -2):

> ## Say: He is Allah, the One! (112:1)
>
> Actually it's - Say (O Muhammad), He is Allah, the One! (112:1)